# Using FILTER on property in SPARQL

Tags: database, sparql, wikidata

How do I select all properties that start with a certain prefix, e.g. `wdt:`? I would like to get all properties related to an item, but am not interested in `schema:`, `rdf:`, `p:` and so on.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p
WHERE {
  wd:Q2 ?p ?entity.
}
```

This query would return *all* properties. I tried using `FILTER(STRSTARTS(?p, "wdt:"))`, `FILTER(STRSTARTS(str(?p), "wdt:"))` and `FILTER(STRSTARTS(xsd:string(?p), "wdt:"))` to check if the property starts with `wdt:`, but the result is always empty.

Comment: `[] wikibase:directClaim ?p` or `FILTER STRSTARTS(STR(?p), STR(wdt:))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wdt: is a prefix, meaning that it's a way to abbreviate something longer.

wdt:P31 is actually stored as

```
http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P31
```

You would in principle have a query where you specify a different prefix, like this:

`PREFIX hello: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>`

And then you would have hello:P31 as your property.

So try using this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p
WHERE {
  wd:Q2 ?p ?entity.
FILTER(STRSTARTS(STR(?p), "http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/"))
```

}

More about prefixes: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/Prefixes

List with explanation of each prefix: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Prefixes_used

Full list of prefxes: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Full_list_of_prefixes